# How to create dynamic method functions in php?

Tags: php, function, model-view-controller, methods

I have a mvc php set up to pull the url and get the data from that. What I want to find out is if it's possible to have a database with unique names, pull the name to check if its in the db and then use the name as a method?

I want to create a simple template with the pulled data from the database, but I want to have many multiples of this website. I was thinking that instead of making a lot of methods with different names that I could do the same thing, but have one method that does the action with a dynamic name to be called upon.

```
class Core {
protected $currentController = 'Pages';
protected $currentMethod = 'index';
protected $params = [];

public function __construct(){
  //print_r($this->getUrl());

  $url = $this->getUrl();

  // Look in controllers for first value
  if(isset($url[0])){
    if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')){
      // If exists, set as controller
      $this->currentContro`enter code here`ller = ucwords($url[0]);
      // Unset 0 Index
      unset($url[0]);
    } 
  }
  

  // Require the controller
  require_once '../app/controllers/'. $this->currentController . '.php';

  // Instantiate controller class
  $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

  // Check for second part of url
  if(isset($url[1])){
    // Check to see if method exists in controller
    if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
      $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
      // Unset 1 index
      unset($url[1]);
    }
  }

  // Get params
  $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

  // Call a callback with array of params
  call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], 
$this->params);
}

public function getUrl(){
  if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    return $url;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes you can use strings as method names in PHP. Google around, you can find examples of how to apply them

Comment: Even though it's possible, it's also oftentimes a sign of bad design. Impossible to tell without knowing (a lot) more about what you want to achieve, though.

Comment: Yes, that is how WP does it. A combination of DB queries and `file_exists( )` Look at their source code under `class-wp-theme.php` for ideas.